# Is <HTML lang="en"> technically an HTML tag?

Tags: html

> HTML tags are the hidden keywords within a web page that define how
>   your web browser must format and display the content.
>
> Most tags must have two parts, an opening and a closing part.
>   [Source](http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/whatishtml.php)

Still, given that definition, I am still not sure if this tag is technically considered an HTML tag. Any illumination would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain why you think it might not be a HTML tag?

Comment: That's a good question. I know <!DOCTYPE html> is not an HTML tag. I know not all HTML tags should have closing tags to make it an HTML tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source of information is misleading. This is what the [official documentation](https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html) says:

> ### 8.1. Writing HTML documents
>
> Documents must consist of the following parts, in the given order:
>
> 1. Optionally, a single `U+FEFF` BYTE ORDER MARK (BOM) character.
> 2. Any number of comments and space characters.
> 3. A `DOCTYPE`.
> 4. Any number of comments and space characters.
> 5. The document element, in the form of an [`<html>`](https://w3c.github.io/html/semantics.html#elementdef-html) element.
> 6. Any number of comments and space characters.
>
> ### 8.1.2. Elements
>
> There are five different kinds of elements: *void elements*, *raw text elements*, *escapable raw text elements*, *foreign elements*, and *normal elements*.
> ...
> **Tags** are used to delimit the start and end of elements in the markup. *Raw text*, *escapable raw text*, and *normal elements* have a start tag to indicate where they begin, and an end tag to indicate where they end. The start and end tags of certain normal elements can be omitted, as described below in the section on *optional tags*. Those that cannot be omitted must not be omitted. *Void elements* only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for *void elements*.

To summarize, `<html>` is the **opening tag** of the [`<html>` element](https://w3c.github.io/html/semantics.html#elementdef-html) which is the one that defines the text as `HTML` (and not other type of [SGML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language)).

Answer (score -1):

The HTML start tag is a tag defined by the HTML language.

…but that definition is rubbish (most tags say very little about formatting or display, and don't have two parts … an *element* is usually defined by a start tag, an end tag and the content between them … but some start tags are optional, and some end tags are either optional or forbidden).

Comment: why is that definition rubbish?